# Heroku rails app (text_area bug)

Tags: text, heroku, area

On the localhost all right...
But in heroku, i can not add more than 255 characters in the "about".

heroku error

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :about %>
<%= f.text_area :about %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p><%= @release.about %></p>
```

thanks!

Comment: What does Heroku logs show for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Is about defined as a `string` in your database?  To be longer than 255 characters it needs to be `text`.  The reason why is because Heroku uses Postgres, who's `string`s can't be longer than 255 characters, while sqlite will allow it.